# How to customize this checkbox that stays checked after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a checkbox list that remains checked even after refreshing with the help of some JS I picked up before. But when I did check it now, it seems that I still have to tweak something on it to fit my needs.

My main concern right now is how to customize this code below to

***No. 1 How to make the following items listed in a list format and keep the checkbox but remove the bullet symbols? For example:***

Checkbox 1

Checkbox 2

Checkbox 3

Checkbox 4

(but not this kind of spacing between each item, more like Ctrl or Shift+ Enter kind of spacing)

***No. 2 How do I add links to the text? For example:***

[Checkbox 1](https://example.com)

[Checkbox 2](https://example.com)

[Checkbox 3](https://example.com)

[Checkbox 4](https://example.com)

I know this is a simple task, although since I am not that good, I cannot figure out how to tweak it on my own. I tried (maybe not hard enough) but failed, so I end up seeking help to figure this code out. Therefore, many thanks in advance to anyone who may help me here.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
    <h3 class="col-lg-9">One Year Through</h3>
    
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <p>This demonstrates how to save the state of a checkbox between page refreshes. Click the checkboxes below and then refresh the page to see how they respond</p>
    <p>The solution uses a class <b>save-cb-state</b> to denote which checkboxes must be persisted</p>
  </div>
<ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox" value="yes"> Checkbox1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox2" value="yes"> Checkbox 2</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox3" value="yes">Checkbox 3</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox4" value="yes"> Checkbox 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- This JavaScript file is required to load the XpressDox interview as well as the code required to run it -->
 
<script>
// Avoid scoping issues by encapsulating code inside anonymous function
(function() {
  // variable to store our current state
  var cbstate;
  
  // bind to the onload event
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the current state from localstorage
    // State is stored as a JSON string
    cbstate = JSON.parse(localStorage['CBState'] || '{}');
  
    // Loop through state array and restore checked 
    // state for matching elements
    for(var i in cbstate) {
      var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + i + '"]');
      if (el) el.checked = true;
    }
  
    // Get all checkboxes that you want to monitor state for
    var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('save-cb-state');
  
    // Loop through results and ...
    for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {
  
      //bind click event handler
      cb[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        // If checkbox is checked then save to state
        if (this.checked) {
          cbstate[this.name] = true;
        }
    
    // Else remove from state
        else if (cbstate[this.name]) {
          delete cbstate[this.name];
        }
    
    // Persist state
        localStorage.CBState = JSON.stringify(cbstate);
      });
    }
  });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you could use JS but probably cookies would be easier but not 100% permanent (eg cookies deleted)

Comment: What to do you mean by *How do I add links to it?*

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry about that, I have already updated my question

Answer (score 1):

This might be the issue with persisting state with `localStorage`...

This:

```
cbstate = JSON.parse(localStorage['CBState'] || '{}');
...
localStorage.CBState = JSON.stringify(cbstate);
```

should be this:

```
cbstate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CBState')) || {}
...
localStorage.setItem('CBState', JSON.stringify(cbstate))
```

The CSS should be something like this:

```
.list-group {
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

The HTML should be something like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox" value="yes">
  <a href="https://example.com">Checkbox 1</a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox2" value="yes">
  <a href="https://example.com">Checkbox 2</a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox3" value="yes"
  <a href="https://example.com">Checkbox 3</a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox4" value="yes">
  <a href="https://example.com">Checkbox 4</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate this help, however I do not understand these codes. I already updated the code with the code you provided above. But may I ask what will change with this?

Comment: The localStorage API requires getItem/setItem to change its properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

The list-style property requires list-style-type be "none" and the left padding removed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Miaplacidus. But may I ask one more thing. First, i want to say that I'm really new in coding and have little knowledge of any other helpful tools. So, what I'm really planning to do is something like this: https://quip.com/2WH9ANqdERWS/One-Year-Through-the-Bible

I want to copy my devotional on my blogspot, but it seems that it can be quite tedious to do this all manually, therefore I would ask if there is a better way? Like an automatic feature where I can just input the text and it will convert to checkbox with link that I put?

Comment: Maybe if you were using a content management system, but that might be too complex for a beginner. I am not sure. If not a CMS you will just have to author it yourself. You can try using a code editor like Atom to make authoring code slightly faster and easier to read.